# event poll data.fd provides me a random value instead c++

Tags: c++, linux, c++20

I tried to register an event poll for socket purposes, but when I tried to use epoll_ctl, the fd reflected a random (usually negative) number instead. I have tested and made sure the fd is correct before passing in, and epoll is created. Is there any way to solve this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

This is compiled in c++20, Linux Ubuntu 22.04

This is a snippet of the code

```
bool
service::engine::BListenerRunner::do_start_telnet_listener(void)
{
    m_socket_tcp_telnet_listener_p = new service::network::BSocketTcp(0, 5000, (60 * 60 * 1000), true);
    if (!m_socket_tcp_telnet_listener_p->do_listen())
    {
        // todo: log error
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Listening to port: " << m_socket_tcp_telnet_listener_p->port() << " on fd: " << m_socket_tcp_telnet_listener_p->fd() << std::endl;
    service::engine::BEventPollRunner::get_instance()->attach(m_socket_tcp_telnet_listener_p->fd(), m_socket_tcp_telnet_listener_p, shared::EVENT_POLL_IN);
    return true;
}
```

```
void
service::engine::BEventPollRunner::attach(int _fd, core::epoll::BEPollSubscriber* _subscriber_p, int _flag)
{
    struct epoll_event event;
    event.events = 0;
    event.data.fd = 0;
    event.data.ptr = (void*) _subscriber_p;

    // EVENT_POLL_IN / OUT is just an enum due to my code architecture, which ensures epoll library is included only in the correct source file.
    if ((_flag & shared::EVENT_POLL_IN)) event.events |= EPOLLIN;
    if ((_flag & shared::EVENT_POLL_OUT)) event.events |= EPOLLOUT;

    if (m_subscribers.find(_fd) == m_subscribers.end())
    {
        if (do_epoll_ctl(EPOLL_CTL_ADD, _fd, &event)) m_subscribers[_fd] = _subscriber_p;
        return;
    }

    do_epoll_ctl(EPOLL_CTL_MOD, _fd, &event);
}
```

```
bool
service::engine::BEventPollRunner::do_epoll_ctl(int _operation, int _fd, epoll_event* _event_p)
{
    int err = epoll_ctl(m_epoll_fd, _operation, _fd, _event_p);
    std::cout << "Adding fd " << _fd << " for op " << _operation << " on epfd " << m_epoll_fd << " err " << err << std::endl;
    if (err != 0)
    {
        switch (errno) // The errors have not implemented printing out.
        {
            case EBADF:
            {} break;
            case EEXIST:
            {} break;
            case EINVAL:
            {} break;
            case ENOENT:
            {} break;
            case ENOMEM:
            {} break;
            case EPERM:
            {} break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

```
epoll_event events[_EVENT_POLL_SIZE_];
int active_epoll = epoll_wait(m_epoll_fd, events, _EVENT_POLL_SIZE_, _EVENT_POLL_TIMEOUT_MS_);
if (active_epoll < 0)
{
    if (errno == EINTR) return;
    else
    {
        // todo: log warn/error
    }
}
    
for (int active = 0; active < active_epoll; ++active)
{
std::cout << "event fpoll fd: " << events[active].data.fd << std::endl;
}
```

During event_wait, the fd displayed would be a random number instead of the supposed socket fd. The socket fd when printed out is as follows:

```
Adding fd 4 for op 1 on epfd 3 err 0
```

```
event fpoll fd: -604570616
```

Comment: Its not random, its just a number that you do not understand where it comes from. Please include the faulty output

Comment: Edited to include the faulty output.

Comment: `event.data` gives you back exactly what you put into it with `epoll_ctl` call. What you put into it is `data.ptr`, but now you are trying to read back `data.fd`. Note that `event.data` is a union. In other words, that weird number is in fact `(int)(void*)_subscriber_p` that you obtained via (apparently unintentional) type punning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Igor Tandetnik's reply, I have removed the ptr reference and now it works. The code should be assigned only the fd or the ptr itself as it is a union. Tested it and now it works.

Comment: It would have been of good etiquette to ask the commenter to carve a response that you'd like to accept, but that's just me.